# Bootstrap Modal binding button actions through functions in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

The following function shows, using Bootstrap and JQuery, a modal. To make it flexible, I want to add as many buttons as I like, and bind functions when those buttons are pressed.

```
blnShowWindow("This is <b>html</b> content", "This is a title", [
{strTitle: 'CCancel', strStyle: 'default', fncAction: function() { alert("ccccc"); } },
{strTitle: 'OOK', strStyle: 'primary', fncAction: function() { alert("ok"); } }]);
```

In a different place:

```
intButtonC = 0;
blnShowWindow = function (htmlContent, strTitle, arrButtons) {
  //....
  $.each(arrButtons, function (intIndex, arrButton) {
    intButtonC += 1;
    strButtonID = "btnModalButton" + intButtonC;
    $("#divModalFooter").html($("#divModalFooter").html() + 
      '<button type="button" class="btn btn-'+arrButton.strStyle+
      '" id="'+strButtonID+'">'+arrButton.strTitle+'</button>');
    $("#"+strButtonID).unbind().bind("click",arrButton.fncAction);
  });
  $("#divModal").modal();
};
```

Both buttons, CCancel and OOK show fine. When clicking OOK, an alert box correctly shows up, with "ok". The problem is, CCancel does not do anything when clicked. Is the array definition correct? What am I doing wrong??

Also is there a better way of defining highly flexible Bootstrap Modals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are overwritting the buttons that has been binding, in the line...

```
 $("#divModalFooter").html($("#divModalFooter").html() + ...
```

for example, if you try this,  the code works

```
intButtonC = 0;
blnShowWindow = function (htmlContent, strTitle, arrButtons) {
  $.each(arrButtons, function (intIndex, arrButton) {
    intButtonC += 1;
    strButtonID = "btnModalButton" + intButtonC;
    $("#divModalFooter").html($("#divModalFooter").html() + 
      '<button type="button" class="btn btn-'+arrButton.strStyle+
      '" id="'+strButtonID+'">'+arrButton.strTitle+'</button>');

  });

    intButtonC = 0;
  $.each(arrButtons, function(intIndex, arrButton){
    intButtonC += 1;
    strButtonID = "btnModalButton" + intButtonC;
    $("#"+strButtonID).unbind().bind("click",arrButton.fncAction);
  });

  $("#divModal").modal();
```

in the other each you bind all the buttons

Comment: You, my man, are one superhero ! I had overseen this. Thank you very much !